# How to Pass Struct as a Argument in solidity?

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x

I have a one struct that of pool config.

```
    struct PoolConfig {
        string name;
        string symbol;
        address[] tokens;
        uint256[] amounts;
        uint256[] weights;
        uint256[] endWeights;
        bool isCorrectOrder;
        uint256 swapFeePercentage;
        bytes userData;
        uint256 startTime;
        uint256 endTime;
    }
     function createPool(PoolConfig memory _poolconfig) public {}
```

I tried in RemixIDE:

```
["SPIDER","SPC",[0x92D463e214D28C3a0F57F770567F24F5203CCcB1,0x04DF6e4121c27633ED22341E7c7Df330F56f289B],[80,20],[95,5],[50,50],true,0,0x00,1617240600,1617242400]
```

Got error :

```
Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1"values":6} value={"types":["tuple(stringstringaddress[]uint256[]uint256[]uint256[]booluint256bytesuint256uint256)"]"values":["[""""[0x92D463e214D28C3a0F57F770567F24F5203CCcB10x04DF6e4121c27633ED22341E7c7Df330F56f289B][8020][955][5050]true""""""1617242400]"]} code=INVALID_ARGUMENT version=abi/5.5.0)
```

Comment: Try surrounding addresses with double quotes, something like `["0x92d4...b1", "0x04df...9b"]`.

Comment: I tried but it get gas error.

Comment: That's fine, one error less. What's the exact error message about gas? You can edit your own question to add more details.